# JFreeChart : Remove comma in X label axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a XYLineChart whith years in X and Integer values in Y. When I render the chart, my years are display like 2,006 and not 2006, certainly because 2006 is a double in my Java program. Is there a wayto remove the comma so I can get 2006 ?

Comment: why would you represent the year as a double and not as an int? To remove the comma you can use String methods.

Comment: Actually I use an int, but when I add it to my XYSeries, it is cast as a double by the methods XYSeries.add(double, double);

Where can I use String methods, I suppose I need to use something like `getXYPlot()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this to format the y axis labels:

```
final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis)chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("####");
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(format);
```

To format the x axis labels, do this:

```
final NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis)chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("####");
domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(format);
```